# glDisable(GL_BLEND): no performance impact on android devices

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, blending

Benchmarking of rendering time of the same set of polygons with:

```
A)  glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc( GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

B)  glDisable( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc( GL_ONE, GL_ZERO );
```

shows that rendering with blending being enabled is indeed slightly slower on the:

- desktop, OpenGL 2.0
- Lenovo P90Pro Intel Atom / PowerVR G6430, OpenGL ES 2.0

and to my confusion, benchmarking on these devices shows no significant difference, which means, I assume, rendering with blending disabled is as performance-costly as with blending being enabled:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab with ARM-A7 / Qualcomm Adreno 305 onboard
- Sony Xperia Z3+ with ARM-A57 / Adreno 430

Why is that? There's SHOULD be a difference, right? Fragment shader being used is pretty straightforward:

```
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D tex;
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_fragmentColor * texture2D(tex, v_texCoord);
}
```

Sorry if definition of the situation is too generic, it's considerably hard to produce minimal working sample suitable to be fit into the SO question. I'm hoping there's some known gotchas around here that I'm missing.

ps: on every tested device resulting image is looks just as expected, with transparency areas with blending being enabled and opaque black - if disabled. the whole question is merely about performance.

Comment: How did you measure it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on graphics, GPUs etc., but if you turn "_rendering with blending disabled is as performance-costly as with blending being enabled_" around to "_rendering with blending enabled is **no more** performance-costly as with blending disabled_" than **(a)** it sounds better (it's a plus, not a problem), and **(b)** to me suggests that [on those devices] there's hardware available to "do the blending" as a normal part of rendering, so making use of it is effectively free.

Comment: Maybe in both cases you see 60 fps, wich is driver/hardware limit. It means that you dont load your gpu hard enough to see the difference in performance. Try to render many-many (thousands?) images to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Even without knowledge of the platforms you mention I can say by own experience that less is not always more. Sometimes branching in code or hw is slower than making a redundant operation. Imagine a branch before every addition in case one operand is 0. So for example when chosing glDisable(GL_BLEND) the driver might set func and eq parameters so that it BEHAVES AS IF disabled, when it really is not. It depends on what the vendor was trying to optimize for. "Worst case" is often the best to optimize, but common case is often also good. Optimizing something unusual and less performance demanding is seldom worth the effort.

For the record I´ve been at platforms rendering 30-50% faster with texturing enabled than disabled, blending a 1x1 white pixel texture with primitive color. That was mindfuck at first but when I thought about it the platform had been continuously optimized for rendering raster maps for almost a decade.